# Update HTML Dropdown List based on Google Calendar Query

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I'm trying to create an HTML form that involves the user selecting a start and end date. Once they selected a date range, I want to have a HTML dropdown update based on whether or not the resource is busy/free on gCal. Is there any way to update the dropdown menu by querying gCal? I'm not really sure how to link the HTML form element to Google service like Calendar.

Here is the sample HTML I am working with:

```
 <form action="action_page.php">
            <!-- Query for start date -->
            Start Date:
            <input type="date" name="startdate", align="center">
            <br/>
            <!-- Query for end date -->
            End Date:
            <input type="date" name="enddate", align="center">
            <input type="submit">
            <br><br>
            <!-- Query for  -->
            <form action="action_page.php">
              <select name="cars">
                <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
                <option value="audi">Audi</option>
              </select>
            </form>
```

Thanks! Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Is this a NON Google website?  If it's an Apps Script Web App, then you can use `google.script.run.serverFunctionName()` to call an Apps Script function, and then send a return value back.  If it's a regular website, you'll need to either use an API, or make an HTTPS request to an Apps Script stand alone script.  If your HTML is using some server side code, you can make an HTTPS request in whatever server language you are using to an Apps Script `doGet()` or `doPost()` function.  Then use content service to send a value back.

Comment: It is a Apps Script web app. So would I just use `google.script.run.serverFunctionName()` to return an array of options to the dropdown form?

Comment: The function `serverFunctionName()` will have a `return [value1, value2];` statement in it.  In order to retrieve the returned array, you must have a `withSuccessHandler(returnedArray)`  The documentation is at the following link:  [Link to Apps Script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withsuccesshandlerfunction)  Look under the HTML tab in the documentation.

Comment: Is there a way to send the values from an HTML form (ie: startdate, enddate) to Apps Script? I'm trying to send the startdate and enddate values to a function that will query Calendar.

Comment: You need to collect the data from the Form.  You can do that multiple ways.  One way is to reference the html form element, which the web app will then convert to an object with the form data matched to `name` attributes.  I see that you have `name` attributes in your form elements, so that will work for that method.  I would remove `action="action_page.php"` from your form tag.  Do you have a submit button in your form?  I don't see a submit button, or any code in a script tag.

Comment: I was going to put two submit buttons. One in the middle to submit the dates and one at the bottom to submit the dropdown selection. I just add `<input type="submit">` right?

Comment: Depending upon the placement, and type of button used, it will submit the form or not when the button is clicked.  What you will want to use depends upon what the overall method is that you are using.  I would not use a `submit` type button.  I would just use a regular button, and get the form element with something like `var myDateForm = document.getElementById('idFormForDates');`  Then use the `myDateForm` element in a `google.script.run` call:  `google.script.run.srvrFncToGetDates(myDateForm);`